# How do I fix the glitch in the simulation?

Tags: cell-to-singularity-evolution

In the Android idle game "Cells" (full name: ["Cell to Singularity: Evolution"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.computerlunch.evolution)), there's a glitch in my primary simulation. It claims to cost 3 megabits per the unlock button.

[image]

When I tap it, a pop-up shows asking if I want to fix the simulation -- but when I select "Fix glitch" nothing seems to happen. The pop-up disappears, but my megabits don't decrease; tapping "unlock" again doesn't do anything.

[image]

If I close the game and reopen it, nothing has changed but the unlock button can be tapped again to trigger the pop-up (but it still behaves as described above.)

How do I unlock this and "fix the glitch" in my simulation?